# thread.join trigger thread.wait(), but why it doesn't need thread monitor?

Tags: java, multithreading, join, monitor

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("end");
}
```

this sentence will throw :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException 
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
```

but use "thread.join()" to replace "thread.wait(0)' doesn't throw any exception.

The puzzle is
I query the thread.join() source code:  it will go to :

```
while(isAlive) 
wait(0);
```

it means they both trigger wait(0). but why the result is so different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another look at the source code and you will find the join is done while holding the monitor (  while synchronized ).  If you want to use "thread.wait(0)" you need to wrap it in a synchronized block or method.

Have a look at:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

```
    Object o = new Object();
    synchronized (o) {
        o.wait(timeInMS);
    }
```

and so in your code try

```
    synchronized (thread) {
        thread.wait(0);
    }
```

Comment: 3ks for your reply. In fact. I am puzzled with "why join method hold the monitor? I can't find any synchronized block in source code" So can you help to solve my puzzle?

Comment: I query the souce code again and find the root cause:     public final synchronized void join(long millis) 
join method is synchorized.so can get the thread's monitor when trigger waiting. 3ks